# swift4: UITableViewHeight content height get fixed height for table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using `swift4`,I have outlet for table view and table view height:

```
@IBOutlet var commentsTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var commentTableHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

the table return dynamic height for each cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

I want to change table view height when get data from `API`:

```
//// Consum APIs
func getProductDetails() {
    API.getProductDetails(category_id: String(self.passed_category_id)) {( error: Error?, success: Bool, products: ProductDetails) in
        if success {
            self.product = products
            self.setProductDetailsValue()
        } else {

        }
    }
}

func setProductDetailsValue() {
if(self.product.comments.count > 0) {
        self.commentsTableView.isHidden = false
        self.commentsTableView.reloadData()
        self.commentsTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.commentTableHeight.constant = self.getTableViewHeight(tableView: self.commentsTableView)

        print("comment table height: ", self.commentTableHeight.constant, self.getTableViewHeight(tableView: self.commentsTableView))
    } else {
        self.commentsTableView.isHidden = true
    }
}
func getTableViewHeight(tableView: UITableView)-> CGFloat {
    tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

    return tableView.contentSize.height
}
```

the print statement prints values like:

```
comment table height:  352.0 624.333324432373
```

which mean that the `self.commentTableHeight.constant` take different value. I find that every time the app give 44 pt to every cell, but I don't know what is the problem with my code.
any help?

Comment: did you layoutIfNeeded() to cell? try cell.layoutIfNeeded() & cell.layoutSubview

Comment: @MAhipalSingh the same result

Comment: Did you take uilabel or uitextview for comment string..

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-layout the  `view`  after changing the constant

```
self.commentTableHeight.constant = self.getTableViewHeight(tableView: self.commentsTableView)
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
print("comment table height: ", self.commentTableHeight.constant, self.getTableViewHeight(tableView: self.commentsTableView))
```

//

you have to put this in `viewDidLoad`

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200; // your estimated height

tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Comment: the same result

Comment: it makes the table view height: 1600.0
set 200 pt to each cell

Comment: You either should use a static height or automatic